# jQuery scroll action only on Wordpress homepage

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scrolltop

I have created code to add fixed class `.menu-bar` to my menu on scroll. My site is on Wordpress and I need fixed menu only on my homepage. I have tried some ways I have found to use this code only on homepage, but I'm a beginner and these didn't work the way I want. Can you help me with this problem?

My code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var menu = $('.menu'),
  scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 100) menu.addClass('menu-bar');
  else menu.removeClass('menu-bar');
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Did you properly enqueued your script in your functions.php? Maybe you can provide a link to your website?

Comment: If your home/front page has a specific class (most themes actually have that), you can then check if the `<body>` element has that class before binding the scroll event listener to the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

add the code in functions.php of you current active theme

If you wish to place this scipt in head on homepage use below code

```
add_action('wp_head','includeMyScript');
function includeMyScript()
{
    if(is_front_page() && is_home())
    {
       echo '<script type="text/javscript>
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var menu = $(".menu"),
            scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 100) menu.addClass("menu-bar");
            else menu.removeClass("menu-bar");
            });
        </script>';
    }

}
```

If you wish to place this scipt in footer before body tag close on homepage use below code

```
add_action('wp_footer','includeMyScript');
function includeMyScript()
{

   if(is_front_page() && is_home())
    {
       echo '<script type="text/javscript>
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var menu = $(".menu"),
            scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 100) menu.addClass("menu-bar");
            else menu.removeClass("menu-bar");
            });
        </script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I added your code, but I have error message `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''),' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in ../public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php` on line 68. It's this line: `if (scroll >= 100) menu.addClass('menu-bar');`

Comment: re check with code i did the mistake of syntax which is reform now sorry...!

Comment: Injecting scripts into the output is generally not a good idea.

Comment: other wise you can inject the script with wp_enque script hook but you are having four lines of code due to that i suggest you this solution other wise you can create a file and inject it with wp_enque_script action.

Comment: I have tried it and it seems not working... I tried below and it worked: 
`if ( window.location.pathname == '/' ) {
   $(window).scroll(function(){
  var menu = $('.menu'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 100) menu.addClass('menu-bar');
  else menu.removeClass('menu-bar');
});
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Create a JS file (my-script.js) with your javascript code. Put it in the theme's root directory.

Next, add the following lines at the end of your theme's functions.php

```
function my_scripts() {
    if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'home-page-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/my-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, false);
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

wp_enqueue_script injects the js files. Read more on the documentation here:
[wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)